# JSON object architecture looks different when I pass it to the client side

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, electron

Here is my Schema

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    requestNumber: String,
    requestedDateTime: String,
    reasons: String,
    state: String,
    hospital: String,
    phone: String,
    status: {type: String, default: 'Pending'},
    latestUpdate: Date,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', messageSchema);
```

Below I am returning the collection with three components in it

```
ipcMain.on('load-requests', function(event) {

  hosSchemaModel.find(function(err, hosSchema) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('inside error') // return res.send(err);
        } else {

          event.sender.send('requests-results', hosSchema) // this line of code passes hosSchema to the client side

          console.log(hosSchema[0].state) //prints the state attribute of the first component in the collection without any errors.

        }
    });
});
```

When I try to `console.log(hosSchema)` in the server, I get the following printed to the terminal:
[image: terminal result]

and I could successfully access the properties such as status of the first component in the collection by referring to its index `hosSchema[0].status`.

Below I am trying to print `hosSchema` to the console (in the front-end)

```
ipcRenderer.on('requests-results', (event, hosSchema) => {
    console.log(hosSchema)
  })
```

I get the result different from what they were looking in the terminal. below is the picture
[image: result in the client-side]

and `hosSchema[0].status` returns undefined.

My questions are:

1) why `hosSchema[0].status` doesn't work in the front-end?

2) what is the correct way to access the properties in the client-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do in the front end is to use `hosSchema[0]._doc.status` instead of `hosSchema[0].status`